# how to write a reduce-per-key function in scheme?

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, scheme, helper

"define a procedure 'reduce-per-key' which a procedure reducef and a list of associations in which each key is paired with a list. The output is a list of the same structure except that each key is now associated with the result of applying reducef to its associated list"

I've already written 'map-per-key' and 'group-by-key' :

```
(define (map-per-key mapf lls)
  (cond
    [(null? lls) '()]
    [else (append (mapf (car lls))(map-per-key mapf (cdr lls)))]))
```

---

```
(define (addval kv lls)
  (cond
    [(null? lls) (list (list (car kv)(cdr kv)))]
    [(eq? (caar lls) (car kv)) 
     (cons (list (car kv) (cons (cadr kv) (cadar lls)))(cdr lls))]
    [else (cons (car lls)(addval kv (cdr lls)))]))

(define (group-by-key lls)
  (cond
    [(null? lls) '()]
    [else (addval (car lls) (group-by-key (cdr lls)))]))
```

how would I write the next step, 'reduce-per-key' ? I'm also having trouble determining if it calls for two arguments or three.

so far, I've come up with:

```
(define (reduce-per-key reducef lls)
  (let loop ((val (car lls))
             (lls (cdr lls)))
    (if (null? lls) val
        (loop (reducef val (car lls)) (cdr lls)))))
```

however, with a test case such as:

```
(reduce-per-key
   (lambda (kv) (list (car kv) (length (cadr kv))))
   (group-by-key
     (map-per-key (lambda (kv) (list kv kv kv)) xs)))
```

I receive an incorrect argument count, but when I try to write it with three arguments, I also receive this error. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is *a lot* more complicated than it needs to be, and has several errors. In fact, the correct answer is simple enough to make unnecessary the definition of new helper procedures. Try working on this skeleton of a solution, just fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (reduce-per-key reducef lls)
  (if (null? lls)        ; If the association list is empty, we're done
      <???>              ; and we can return the empty list.
      (cons (cons <???>  ; Otherwise, build a new association with the same key 
                  <???>) ; and the result of mapping `reducef` on the key's value
            (reduce-per-key <???> <???>)))) ; pass reducef, advance the recursion
```

Remember that there's a built-in procedure for mapping a function over a list. Test it like this:

```
(reduce-per-key (lambda (x) (* x x))
                '((x 1 2) (y 3) (z 4 5 6)))

> '((x 1 4) (y 9) (z 16 25 36))
```

Notice that each association is composed of a key (the `car` part) and a list as its value (the `cdr` part). For example:

```
(define an-association '(x 3 6 9))
(car an-association)
> 'x       ; the key
(cdr an-association)
> '(3 6 9) ; the value, it's a list
```

As a final thought, the name `reduce-per-key` is a bit misleading, `map-per-key` would be a lot more appropriate as this procedure can be easily expressed using `map` ... but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

**UPDATE:**

Now that you've found a solution, I can suggest a more concise alternative using `map`:

```
(define (reduce-per-key reducef lls)
  (map (lambda (e) (cons (car e) (map reducef (cdr e))))
       lls))
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain I've correctly filled the blanks except for (;the result of mapping 'reducef' on the key's value)

Comment: is it     (reducef (cdr lls)) ? @Óscar López

Comment: Nope, just use the built-in `map` procedure (read about it in the documentation of your Scheme interpreter). Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: `(define (reduce-per-key reducef lls)
  (if (null? lls)   
      '()                          
      (cons (cons (car lls)                    
                  (map reducef (cdr lls)))               
            (reduce-per-key reducef (cdr lls)))))`

Comment: You almost got it. There are a couple of problems in the second and third <???>'s. Remember: you're operating over the _first_ element of the list, which happens to be an association. Hint: there are a couple of `a`'s missing.